# Overfull \hbox with komascript and \newlength in texlive 2015

Tags: texlive, koma-script

The following mwe

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newlength{\testlength}
\setlength{\testlength}{.75\linewidth}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\testlength]{demo}

\includegraphics{demo}

\includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{demo}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with:

```
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14
```

gives

[image]

after updating to texlive 2015

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16
```

[image]

and

```
Zeile 6: Overfull \hbox (5736.69446pt too wide) in paragraph
```

I would like to define a width for all my figures, is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I compile with TeX Live 2014, adding `\showthe\linewidth`, I get

```
418.25555pt
```

With TeX Live 2015, instead, I get

```
8191.99998pt
```

This is apparently due to a change in KOMA-Script classes. On the other hand, it doesn't make much sense to set the length to `0.75\linewidth` in the preamble, because `\linewidth` is a length that varies in the document.

You probably want

```
\newcommand\testlength{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth\relax}
```

so `\testlength` can take the current value of `\linewidth`. Or, if you want the length to be three quarters of the text width, do

```
\newlength{\testlength}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\testlength{0.75\columnwidth}}
```